# Iteration and comparison of entity handles in 3 loops

Tags: vba, loops, automation, autocad

I am trying to write a code for matching two handles (string) obtained from different loops. One is obtained from outer loop, another one is obtained from a nested loop, because these two are associated. I am comparing and storing the result obtained from second loop into a variant. But the process is very slow. Because outer most loop loops over 800 times, middle one around 400 and inner most runs 80 times for each run of outer loops and so on.

```
'Cycling through groups, and getting handle for entities attached to the group
Dim acGroup As AcadGroup
Dim acGroupEnt As AcadEntity
Dim ghandle As String
Dim gehandle As String
Dim ehandle As String
'Dim group_entity_handle_array As Variant
Dim l As Integer
Dim selected_group_array As Variant
For Each acEnt In acSelSet
    ehandle = acEnt.Handle
    For Each acGroup In ThisDrawing.Groups
        'Debug.Print ("Group Name: " & acGroup.Name)
        ghandle = acGroup.Handle
        For Each acGroupEnt In acGroup
           'Debug.Print ("    " & acGroupEnt.ObjectName & " ... " & acGroupEnt.Handle)
           gehandle = acGroupEnt.Handle
                If ehandle = gehandle Then
                    selected_group_array = ghandle
                    'Debug.Print "Group Handle:  " & ghandle
                End If
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Is there any possible way for doing so with least amount of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you can exit the loop as soon as you have found your group (`Goto`). May be you can also use a variable to hold the list of groups in order to avoid a lookup in `ThisDrawing.Groups`. And may be you can use `ObjectID` instead of handles. Comparing `LongPtr` should be faster than strings.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim acSelSet As AcadSelectionSet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set acSelSet = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add("SS1")
    If Err <> 0 Then
       Set acSelSet = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets("SS1")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    acSelSet.SelectOnScreen
    Dim acGroup As AcadGroup
    Dim acGroupEnt As AcadEntity
    Dim gid As LongPtr
    Dim geid As LongPtr
    Dim eid As LongPtr
    Dim group_entity_handle_array As Variant
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim selected_group_array As Variant
    Dim groups As AcadGroups
    Set groups = ThisDrawing.groups
    For Each acEnt In acSelSet
        eid = acEnt.ObjectID
        For Each acGroup In groups
            Debug.Print ("Group Name: " & acGroup.Name)
            gid = acGroup.ObjectID
            For Each acGroupEnt In acGroup
               Debug.Print ("    " & acGroupEnt.ObjectName & " ... " & acGroupEnt.Handle)
               geid = acGroupEnt.ObjectID
                If eid = geid Then
                    selected_group_array = gid
                    Debug.Print "Group ID:  " & gid
                    GoTo selectedGroupArrayFound
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
selectedGroupArrayFound:
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Maxence, i'll try that tomorrow. I'll test and update if i am doing it right.

Comment: I tried the above code, but it gives error on the declaration of LongPtr as "User-Defined Type Not Defined". Then i searched over internet, i replaced it as Long. Now, the new error using ObjectID gives as "Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an automation type not supported in visual basic." How can i get over this.

Comment: AutoCAD 2011 for mechanical Drawing i am using

Comment: OK, so you're using a 32-bit VBA, it's the reason why there is no LongPtr on your system. You should continue to use handles on such an old system because there are 32/64-bit issues.